# Ionic - Error with cordova ios after update npm

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to generate ios folder and I run this command `ionic cordova platform add ios@4.4.0` but it returns me this:

```
[ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@4.4.0

Adding ios project...
        Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
            Path: platforms/ios
            Package: com.zs.app
            Name: App name
        iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.4.0
        Error: Source path does not exist: resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png
```

I did this always and this works just give me the error now and I don't understand why.

If I run `ionic cordova platform check ios` returns this:

```
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova platform check (exit code 1):


    android @ 6.2.3; current did not install, and thus its version cannot be determined
    ios @ 4.4.0; current did not install, and thus its version cannot be determined
    cp: no such file or directory:
    /var/folders/hz/kg3_3dz134x4lvxrjbv5shc40000gn/T/cordova-platform-check-1512380413642/platforms/ios/HelloCordova/.gitignore

    grep: no such file or directory:
    /var/folders/hz/kg3_3dz134x4lvxrjbv5shc40000gn/T/cordova-platform-check-1512380413642/platforms/ios/HelloCordova.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

    sed: no such file or directory:
    /var/folders/hz/kg3_3dz134x4lvxrjbv5shc40000gn/T/cordova-platform-check-1512380413642/platforms/ios/HelloCordova.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

    Error: Entry not found in project file for sub-project: CordovaLib/CordovaLib.xcodeproj
```

Anyone can help me? How can I solve that?

Thank you

Comment: Did you updated any of IONIC libraries?

Comment: I update npm @Saikat1529

Comment: And don't generate ios folder resources @Saikat1529 . How can I solve that?

Comment: I also had the same problem. I tried to downgrade my npm, but was not helpful. I believe its a bug in IONIC side. Then I generated those folders and images manually by Photoshop. And it works fine.

Comment: Ok, Thank you @Saikat1529